# Keep bootable backup with rsync

Tags: backup, rsync

I've ditched Carbon Copy Cloner now that it went commercial, well I felt guilty about using a closed source application anyways.

What `rsync` options do you prefer when maintaining your bootable backups?

```
rsync -avhHXR --delete --progress --hfs-compression --protect-decmpfs --stats --exclude=/Volumes / /Volumes/Backup
```

Just by way of explanation : Any large recursive backup wants the archive option `-a` of course.  And ideally the `-H` option for hard-links.  We need `-R` and `--exclude=/Volumes` since we're using `/` as the source.  We want `--delete` to delete files not present on the source.  All the option `-vh`, `--progress`, and `--stats` only impact the display. And `-X`, `--hfs-compression`, and `--protect-decmpfs` preserve various HFS+ features.

Add a `-n` for testing before running the actual backup of course.

Just a few questions :

In Linux, you might want `-S` for sparse files, but [afaik HFS+ lacks sparse files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/52247/13192) anyways.  I'd leave out `-A` too since HFS+ lacks acls too.  I presume that's correct?

Are there any benefits to `--inplace`?  Would it reduce wear?  It's slightly risky if the transfer breaks perhaps.  It conflicts with `-S` in Linux, btw.

Am I missing anything particularly useful here?

Anything about making a new disk bootable that isn't bootable already?

Comment: I'll check out a couple more options I see being used here : https://www.davidwaring.net/projects/backup.html

Comment: Just found a bit more at  http://nicolasgallagher.com/mac-osx-bootable-backup-drive-with-rsync/  and  https://static.afp548.com/mactips/image.html  but maybe a bit dated.

Answer (score 2):

Just found an open source backup script [Counterpart](https://github.com/jedda/Counterpart) ([jedda.me](http://jedda.me/projects/counterpart/)) which does exactly this, seemingly does stuff CCC misses too.

Comment: And there is this : https://github.com/necolas/dotfiles