# After Changing Partition Type From FFFF I Can't Boot

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, mount, core-storage

I originally asked the following question: [Partition Type: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF Macbook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/261980/partition-type-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-macbook-pro) about how to change my partition type from an unknown to a normal one, since it was unmountable.

I was able to and I can now view all of my files, however I cannot boot from it. When I tried verifying it with Disk Utility I received the error:Invalid Disk Label @ 4096: cksum mismatch, and when verifying the partition I get the same error.

After Googling, I found that this was most likely caused by a bad installation of the OS. So  I tried to reinstall the latest version of Mac OS Sierra, until the installer said "This disk cannot be used to start up your computer."
Here is all of my info:

```
sh-3.2# cd /Volumes/Internal/
sh-3.2# ls -la
total 72
      2 drwxr-xr-x   35 root          wheel   1258 Nov  6 22:02 .
  13744 drwxrwxrwt@   5 root          admin    170 Nov 22 11:55 ..
3976587 -rw-rw-r--    1 root          admin  15364 Nov 22 10:53 .DS_Store
 448963 d--x--x--x   10 root          wheel    340 Nov 22 11:52 .DocumentRevisions-V100
4414129 -rw-r--r--    1 root          wheel    591 Nov  6 22:01 .OSInstallerMessages
 458404 drwxr-xr-x@   2 root          wheel     68 Nov 20 16:57 .PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware
     20 drwx------    5 root          admin    170 Oct  8 13:08 .Spotlight-V100
 498780 d-wx-wx-wt    3 root          wheel    102 Oct  8 18:29 .TemporaryItems
     26 d-wx-wx-wt@   2 root          wheel     68 Nov 22 11:52 .Trashes
3976588 ----------    1 root          admin      0 Jul 30 14:32 .file
     24 drwx------   11 root          admin    374 Nov 22 11:52 .fseventsd
3976589 drwxr-xr-x@   2 root          wheel     68 Nov  6 21:57 .vol
3976590 drwxrwxr-x+ 141 root          admin   4794 Nov 20 18:44 Applications
2719236 drwxr-xr-x    4 root          wheel    136 Oct 29 12:18 EFI
4051944 drwxr-xr-x+  63 root          wheel   2142 Nov 12 12:19 Library
4082330 drwxr-xr-x@   2 root          wheel     68 Nov  6 21:57 Network
3976557 drwxr-xr-x@   4 root          wheel    136 Nov  6 21:53 System
1961160 drwxrwxrwx@  13 Thoughtyness  staff    442 Oct 16 01:28 Twixtor5
1962231 drwxrwxrwx@   9 Thoughtyness  staff    306 Oct 16 01:28 Twixtor5AEManual
 412912 drwxr-xr-x    6 root          admin    204 Nov  6 22:02 Users
 412916 drwxr-xr-x@   4 root          wheel    136 Nov 20 20:58 Volumes
4394376 drwxr-xr-x@  38 root          wheel   1292 Oct 21 04:07 bin
4394413 drwxrwxr-t@   2 root          admin     68 Nov  6 21:57 cores
4394414 dr-xr-xr-x@   2 root          wheel     68 Nov  6 21:57 dev
4394415 lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root          wheel     11 Nov  6 21:56 etc -> private/etc
4415298 dr-xr-xr-x@   2 root          wheel     68 Nov  6 22:02 home
4394416 -rw-r--r--@   1 root          wheel    313 Sep 23 19:18 installer.failurerequests
 434287 dr-xr-xr-x@   2 root          wheel     68 Oct  8 13:44 net
3976539 drwxr-xr-x@   6 root          wheel    204 Nov  6 21:57 private
4395069 drwxr-xr-x@  63 root          wheel   2142 Nov  6 21:56 sbin
4395131 lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root          wheel     11 Nov  6 21:56 tmp -> private/tmp
4395132 drwxr-xr-x@  10 root          wheel    340 Nov  6 22:00 usr
4413886 lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root          wheel     11 Nov  6 21:56 var -> private/var

sh-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI NO NAME                 209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         450.1 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Internal               *449.7 GB   disk1
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *31.4 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Fixer OS                30.5 GB    disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s3

sh-3.2# gpt -r show /dev/disk0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  879039128      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  879448768   97656259         
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header

sh-3.2# gpt -r show /dev/disk1
gpt show: unable to open device '/dev/disk1': Resource busy

sh-3.2# gpt -r show /dev/disk2
     start      size  index  contents
         0         1         PMBR
         1         1         Pri GPT header
         2        32         Pri GPT table
        34         6         
        40    409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    409640  59662480      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  60072120   1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  61341656         7         
  61341663        32         Sec GPT table
  61341695         1         Sec GPT header

sh-3.2# dd if=/dev/disk0s2 count=3 | hexdump
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
1536 bytes transferred in 0.000717 secs (2142485 bytes/sec)
0000000 b1 93 d1 22 ff ff ff ff 01 00 10 00 00 00 1c 02
0000010 af 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000020 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000030 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000040 00 30 25 ca 68 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000050 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 43 53 01 00 00 00 04 00
0000060 00 10 00 00 00 00 40 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000070 01 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 52 9a 8c 06 00 00 00 00
0000080 52 9e 8c 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000090 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00000a0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
00000b0 72 ab b7 ed 17 41 cc 2a b3 59 3d 7c 06 00 ce 3c
00000c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000130 b1 df 08 84 aa 00 41 c7 a3 23 5f b5 72 ae 20 f2
0000140 ec e6 54 9c 1e 60 45 f5 8c fd 27 9d 7c 11 f6 a0
0000150 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000600
```

Any ideas on how to boot from this?
My only idea would be to create a second partition, install Mac OS Sierra on that, slowly start copying files and resizing the partition until all of my files would be on the new partition, qt which point I could delete the current one and just use the second one, however I'm sure there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Your CoreStorage Logical Volume Group or better: the comprised Logical Volume is missing a proper [volume header](http://dubeiko.com/development/FileSystems/HFSPLUS/tn1150.html#VolumeHeader). Usually the volume header starts at the 1024th Byte of a partition and has a length of 512 Bytes.

With other words:  your volume is missing a 3rd block with a content similar to this one:

```
0000400 48 2b 00 04 80 00 21 00 48 46 53 4a 00 00 01 ff
0000410 d1 98 a4 93 d4 33 8b d5 00 00 00 00 d1 98 88 73
0000420 00 06 07 53 00 01 82 39 00 00 10 00 00 fb 6a 00
0000430 00 c5 1c 55 00 25 73 c7 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00
0000440 00 0d e2 65 00 3e a2 fb 00 00 00 00 02 20 00 fb
0000450 00 00 00 31 00 06 b9 ef 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000460 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 31 fb 48 1e a0 6c 47 a2 9f
0000470 00 00 00 00 00 1f e0 00 00 1f e0 00 00 00 01 fe
0000480 00 00 00 01 00 00 01 fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000490 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
00004c0 00 00 00 00 00 60 00 00 00 60 00 00 00 00 06 00
00004d0 00 00 0a 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00004e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000510 00 00 00 00 0e 40 00 00 01 30 00 00 00 00 e4 00
0000520 00 00 10 00 00 00 e4 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0000530 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000560 00 00 00 00 11 d0 00 00 01 30 00 00 00 01 1d 00
0000570 00 02 80 00 00 00 72 00 00 13 30 97 00 00 13 00
0000580 00 15 c5 aa 00 00 13 00 00 18 2d 23 00 00 13 00
0000590 00 19 d8 fb 00 00 13 00 00 1b 76 cb 00 00 13 00
00005a0 00 1c 34 70 00 00 13 00 00 1d 0e 4d 00 00 13 00
00005b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
*
0000600
```

The volume header of your volume contains zeros only.

Without direct disk access I can guess the reasons only:

- maybe the volume was "repaired to bits" by `diskutil repairDisk disk0` or  `diskutil repairVolume disk0s1` (unlikely)
- a wrong **alternate** volume header filled with zeros replaced the proper volume header
- the partition map of the disk was manipulated accidentally (e.g. trying to delete the Debian partitions, you also deleted the macOS recovery partition or the macOS recovery partition and the CoreStorage container have been fused).

---

To further diagnose the disk it would require direct access (e.g. via TeamViewer) to check various invisible disk structures. It's too difficult and lengthy to answer all possible circumstances comprehensively without disk access.

Examples how lengthy solution processes are (these are **no** answers to your question):

- [BootCamp Partition Error!! Help. Deleted EFI Partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257662/93229)
- [Missing Mac partitions - unrecognized file system](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222792/93229)

As an alternative you can try to rsync the content of the volume to an external disk. With the proper options set the external volume should be bootable afterwards.

Links:

- [Mac OS X bootable backup drive with rsync](http://nicolasgallagher.com/mac-osx-bootable-backup-drive-with-rsync/)
- [Keep bootable backup with rsync](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182454/keep-bootable-backup-with-rsync)

Comment: Thank you, I know the problem is that I deleted the recoevry OS partition. How may I fix this problem?

Comment: @Thoughtyness It depends on how you "deleted" the recovery partition. You can try to restore it by unmounting disk0: `diskutil umountDisk disk0` and add it with: `sudo gpt add -i 3 -b 879448768 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0`. But I don't think the **missing** Recovery HD is the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I deleted it in Mac Os X Utilities, as for the commands I did them yet on the second one received this error:"gpt add: unable to open device 'disk0': Resource busy". I trust your judgment in thinking that isn't the cause, so I won't pursue that. I do however think it might have something to do with the fact that I have a 500gb ssd yet ~50gb si missing. In Disk Utility is says 49.87gb partition is "Free Space". Yet it's not part of the only partition and I can't create a partition in its place, nor can I delete it. Here's a screenshot: http://bit.ly/2gjyvPG

Comment: @Thoughtyness Oh I forgot: first eject "Internal", then retry with `diskutil umountDisk disk0` and `sudo gpt ...`. The unallocated 50 GB are the deleted Recovery HD and the deleted 2-3 Kali partitions (swap, / etc).

Comment: I have since tried to reinstall the OS from the Mac OS X Utilities, however since I have Mac OS Sierra installed on the partition and for some reason I have Mac OS X utilities  I can't do a reinstall from there. I checked, and between my two hard drives and 3 flash drives I don't have enough storage to back up all of my files and do a full reinstall. Also after delving deeper into my system files I found that a lot of them had the wrong permissions set to them. Is there a way I can, if you want me to, send you my TeamViewer info?